# Surjective Linear mapping between different vector spaces

Tags: linear-transformations

I've learned from theorem 9.5 in Rudin PMA that if $A \in L(X)$, then $A$ is injective if and only if $A$ is surjective.

Suppose now I have a linear transformation $A \in L(X,Y)$. Now we know $X$ and $Y$ have the same dimension and $A$ maps $X$ onto $Y$, I would like to know if we can say $A$ is injective, thus invertible? What if $X$ and $Y$ are of different dimensions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, on $\mathcal L(X)$, in your case of a f. d. v. space, $\text{epimorphism}\iff\text{full}\operatorname{rank}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that finite dimensional vector spaces of the same dimension are isomorphic.

If $X$ and $Y$ are finite dimensional, then if their dimensions are the same, $A$ surjective implies $A$ invertible.

Not true when the dimensions are different.  Consider $A:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ by $A(x,y)=x$.  The kernel is nontrivial, so it's not invertible.

In fact, when the dimensions are finite and different, $A$ can't be invertible.  If it was invertible, it would be an isomorphism.

In terms of matrices, the matrix would have to be square for there to be a two-sided inverse. That indicates $\operatorname{dim}V=\operatorname{dim}W$.

In the infinite dimensional case, this breaks down.  Consider the "shift operator" on the space $\mathcal l_1$ of sequences, given by $(x_1,x_2,\dots)\mapsto (x_2,x_3,\dots)$.  It's surjective, but not injective.

And, $(x_1,x_2,\dots)\mapsto (0,x_1,\dots)$ is injective but not surjective.